# How to debug list view problems?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a list view with some complex layouts.
Some parts of the layouts are set visible/adjusted at runtime (i.e. not everything set by the xml).
It has caught my attention than in some "rare" cases there is a specific part (the same in all cases) that is rendered visually either a few seconds after looking at the list item or if I scroll down the list and then scoll back up again.
What I observe is that it seems like after a few seconds the list item is "redrawn" and the item suddenly appears.
I have added debug output to check for its visibility and according to the console log, the item is visible when the `getView` is called for that the first time.
So I have no idea what the issue might be.
How can I debug issues like this?

Comment: Please add your getView() method code.

Comment: @sider:The code is too much to post, and I have not been able to pinpoint the actual place this might happening so that I can write a small example that would reproduce it to post it here

Comment: @Jim Systematically stripping code and checking the problem still persists does that for you. Heck, you might even solve it that way ^^

Comment: @nhaarman:I was wondering if there are any tools that might help. I noticed that when I tried to get a snapshot using the hierarchy viewer by the time the snapshot is taken the element appeared. So I have not managed to even get a snapshot to inspect the hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in the developer pane on your cellphone that flash every time a piece of screen change.

You can also use something like this https://github.com/JakeWharton/scalpel

Comment: Where is this option Tehre?

Comment: sorry, my dyslexia strikes again

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an android device you can activate 'developer options' (you'll have to google how to do this for your device as it varies) like Luca said. These are really cool because you can see where changes appear on the screen and add layout borders etc which make it easier to see exactly what is happening. They can be really useful for debugging sometimes!

I had a similar problem and I tried removing most of my code and adding chunks back in to make sure they were working and eventually you should be able to locate at least the general area where the problem is.

Good luck! Sometimes these things can take a while!